# Cannot perform a segue from my class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I am working with the library KYCircleMenu. You can find it over [here](https://github.com/Kjuly/KYCircleMenu). I am also working with storyboards. I made a Class MenuViewController that is derived from KYCircleMenu

```
@interface MenuViewController : KYCircleMenu
```

Next I have implemented my initWithCoder like this.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    if(self = [self initWithButtonCount:kKYCCircleMenuButtonsCount
                              menuSize:kKYCircleMenuSize
                            buttonSize:kKYCircleMenuButtonSize
                 buttonImageNameFormat:kKYICircleMenuButtonImageNameFormat
                      centerButtonSize:kKYCircleMenuCenterButtonSize
                 centerButtonImageName:kKYICircleMenuCenterButton
       centerButtonBackgroundImageName:kKYICircleMenuCenterButtonBackground]) 
    { 
        
        
    } 
    return self;
}
```

And finally I have implemented a method from the KyCicrleMenu `RunButtonActions`. This method tells me what button is pressed in the menu. So in this method I am trying to do a segue to another viewcontroller. I am doing it like this.

```
 NSLog(@"tag is %d",[sender tag]);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNews" sender:self];
```

(The log gives me the button tag from the button that is pressed).
For some reason or another I keep getting this error.

```
Receiver (<MenuViewController: 0x1cd7cf50>) has no segue with identifier 'showNews''
```

Here is a screenshot from my storyboard.

[image]

Can anybody help me with this annoying problem?

Kind regards

Comment: You forgot to call super initWithCoder: ?

Comment: What should I do inside the initWithCodeR?

Comment: where is the code for performing the segue written?

Comment: You can see it above ?  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showNews" sender:self];

Answer (score 1):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    if(self = [self initWithButtonCount:kKYCCircleMenuButtonsCount
                              menuSize:kKYCircleMenuSize
                            buttonSize:kKYCircleMenuButtonSize
                 buttonImageNameFormat:kKYICircleMenuButtonImageNameFormat
                      centerButtonSize:kKYCircleMenuCenterButtonSize
                 centerButtonImageName:kKYICircleMenuCenterButton
       centerButtonBackgroundImageName:kKYICircleMenuCenterButtonBackground]) 
    { 


    } 
    return self;
}
```

Here, you are doing nothing with the `aDecoder` object - this contains all of the information from the storyboard (including the segue). Instead you are creating a brand new object, ignoring anything you have set up in the storyboard.

I've had a quick look at the repository and it doesn't seem to be tailored towards use in a storyboard - it implements its own loadView method, it has a designated initialiser and so on. You'd have to play around with it to set those properties after calling `[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];`, perhaps by pulling out the setup code from the designated initialiser and putting it into a separate method.